# Importing operator last in Angular/Rxjs app

Tags: angular, import, rxjs5

I'm struggling importing the `last` operator in my Angular 5 app. We're using Rxjs 5.5.2.

What I do is:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/last';

/* ... */
getData() {
  return Observable.last(/* ... */);
}
```

And I get a `Property 'last' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.` error...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it as a constuctor. So the import would be: `'rxjs/add/observable/last'`

Comment: I get ` Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/observable/last' ` :(

Comment: but you're right, I used to do `Observable.from().last()` and for no reason I switched to `Observable.last()` !

Answer (score 0):

RxJS 5.5 introduces so-called lettable operators. Use this syntax:

```
import { last} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJS 5.5 introduces so-called lettable operators. Use this syntax:

```
import { last} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Then you need to wrap it in a pipe:

```
myObservable
  .pipe( last())
  .subscribe()
```